# Customizing Terraform Input

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have to take 7 inputs from the user in Terraform. Each time when i take input, it shows "Enter a value", which will give user a little confusion.

[image]

Can i change "Enter a Value" to my custom like "Enter AWS Region" and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an argument "description" inside your variable declaration block. It is used to give a human-friendly description for that variable which is primarily for documentation for users using your Terraform configuration. Terraform will prompt the description when asking to input value.

```
variable "bucket_name"{
    description = "A cool name for your bucket."
    type = "string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bash wrapper around terraform using bash and define a few TF_VAR_name variables before you call the terraform command.